# atob function shouldn't be used in new code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, base64, deprecation-warning

I need to use `atob` function in a React project I'm working on, but VSCode puts a line through the function call and on hover I get the following message:

> This function is only provided for compatibility with legacy web
> platform APIs and should never be used in new code, because they use
> strings to represent binary data and predate the introduction of typed
> arrays in JavaScript. For code running using Node.js APIs, converting
> between base64-encoded strings and binary data should be performed
> using `Buffer.from(str, 'base64')` and `buf.toString('base64')`.

The code still works as expected, but I was wondering if it is safe to use `atob` or there is maybe some other solution which I am unaware of?

Comment: I don't know why VS Code is so against using `atob`. It is not deprecated and is [still apart of the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-atob-dev)

Comment: Yea also that explanation makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify that the script is being used in a browser to make vs code stop complaining?

Comment: I do not see this error in VSCode. It could be throwing the warning assuming yours is a nodejs project.

Comment: Maybe has something to see with `React StrictMode`?

Comment: suggestion is also wrong, because Buffer class exists only in Nodejs not in browser (browsers have different way like Blob & ArrayBuffer)

Comment: I suspect you mistakenly imported a nodejs package or otherwise reconfigured your vscode to make it assume you're writing code for node.js. [`global.atob` is indeed deprecated in Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#atobdata).

Comment: I thought also that VS Code thinks I am writing node project but I've selected React in language mode

Comment: @bogdanoff Might be why the first part of the sentence is there, "For code running using Node.js APIs," :) Not that it's grammatically correct, mind you, but at least they mention Node.js...