# How to decode a token in Next.js middleware?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

I am setting an encoded cookie in one of my nextjs component

```
setCookie("_SYS_USER_AUTH", window.btoa(res?.data));
```

I want to access the same in Nextjs middleware like this

```
export function middleware(request) {
  const { cookies, url } = request;
  const jwt = cookies.get(`_SYS_USER_AUTH`);
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/account")) {
     console.log(window.btoa(jwt));
  }
}
```

Here I am getting window is not defined error. Is there any other way I can decode this in nextjs middleware?

Comment: Have you tried simply calling `console.log(btoa(jwt))`, without referencing `window`?

Comment: This method is working but with a warning.

This function is only provided for compatibility with legacy web platform APIs and should never be used in new code, because they use strings to represent binary data and predate the introduction of typed arrays in JavaScript. For code running using Node.js APIs, converting between base64-encoded strings and binary data should be performed using

Comment: It should be fine to use in Middleware (Edge runtime). That warning is most likely assuming the code is running in Node.js, see [atob function shouldn't be used in new code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72941913/atob-function-shouldnt-be-used-in-new-code). You can disregard it.